# How to do JNDI lookup which is server independent?

Tags: jndi

We have to reuse a certain piece of code which has some jdbc calls. The existing code is in jar which we cannot modify. They are doing JNDI lookup for db connection something like this

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:jdbc/testDB");
```

This works fine in JBoss, but we are trying to use the same in Tomcat server and it fails. After bit of googling I found that for tomcat I need to do something like this.

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java/comp/env/:jdbc/testDB");
```

I cannot modify the code to have java/comp/env just for tomcat. Is there a server independent way(by some config file) to have this resolved such that I can find the resource without modifying the code?

Answer (score 0):

That "certain piece of code" is - what? In case of `EJB, Servlet, JSP`.. you can perform injection:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/testDB")
DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: Sorry the certain piece of code is the one I dont have access to(basically thats a third party service which does database lookup) the in which there is Context Lookup. So I cant add the annotation as you have mentioned

Comment: But how do you plan to change anything if you don't have access to the code? :)

Comment: I was thinking if there is server config that I can change so that I don't have to modify edit code. For example the code remains the same, the way jndi resource name is specified is changed using some xml file(server dependent way)

Comment: I am not aware of such (server dependent) way, if it exist then it's related to the deployment descriptor file; try this link: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/globalresources.html